# PATH setting doesn't always work for python36 in windows shell

Tags: windows, path

The python 3.6 in my Win7 laptop has been installed under C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32 and the path has been added to the environment PATH with the Scripts path.

I could just type python to launch it from any command window, so I think the PATH setting is working.

But then, the following registry setting is used by me to launch some python script from the directory context menu:

```
reg add "HKCR\Directory\shell\unLog" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "un-Log" /f
reg add "HKCR\Directory\shell\unLog\command" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "python.exe \"%~dp0log.py\" \"%%1\"" /f
```

Whenever I click the unLog in the context menu, it would always tell me that it can't find the executable file -- If I change the "python.exe" to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe", it would work also, so the PATH setting doesn't work in this case?

I've used py.exe to replace python.exe to make it works again, since the launcher py.exe is under C:\Windows folder. But I still don't know why the previous setting fails. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: A template command should use a fully-qualified path for the executable. The Windows shell API won't search `PATH`. However, if you check in a debugger, you'll see that, at least in Windows 10, it does look in the [known folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457) `FOLDERID_System` and `FOLDERID_Windows` via the undocumented function `_PathFindInSystem` from the WinRT Storage API library windows.storage.dll. So it seems you can access system executables without using a fully-qualified path, but I'd use the full path in that case, too.

Comment: BTW, you should avoid using the HKCR predefined handle to create registry keys. That's a combined view of the user and machine `Software\Classes`, and whether the key is created per user or per machine depends on the existing keys. It's better to create the key explicitly for the user or machine.

Comment: @eryksun, thanks for your explanation, I'll try to find a way to get the full-qualified path of python executable in a windows batch script.

Comment: @eryksun, thanks also for the advice about HKCR:)

Comment: You can `call` a subroutine to search `PATH`. Say `%1` is "python.exe", then `%~f$PATH:1` is the full path if it's found. If `%2` has the name of a variable to set as an output parameter, the whole statement would be `set "%~2=%~f$PATH:1"`. Or you could instead use `for /f "delims=" %i in ('python -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"') do set "PYTHON=%i"`.